# Flutter Convert Switch

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am building a website on flutter and want to add functionality to swap between light and dark themes. I have achieved this goal using a switch that swaps between the themes however I want to replace the switch itself with an icon that will swap as the themes swap.

I have the following:

In the appbar:

```
actions: const [
            ChangeThemeButtonWidget(),
          ],
```

In the ChangeThemeButtonWidget()

```
class ChangeThemeButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChangeThemeButtonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

    return Switch.adaptive(
      value: themeProvider.isDarkMode,
      onChanged: (value) {
        final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
        provider.toggleTheme(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and within my themeprovider

```
class ThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The issue comes when I attempt to replace the switch with a button, no matter what I use It does not trigger a change. Ideally I would like to use a button using the Icons.light_mode and Icons.dark_mode, I already know how to swap them based on the theme I just can't figure out how to have the button trigger the swap.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Edit: Material app:

```
void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
        builder: (context, _) {
          final themeprovider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: "Test",
            // onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) =>
            //     AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appTitle,
            themeMode: themeprovider.themeMode,
            theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
            darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
            routes: appRoutes,
          );
        },
      );
}
```

Comment: Can you include your material app?

Comment: Added Material app

Comment: May we see the code for your button? If the switch works, then a button should work just as well

Comment: Did you replace `Switch` with `IconButton` or just with `Icon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have different themes on two modes. You can follow this snippet.

```dart
class ChangeThemeButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChangeThemeButtonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).isDarkMode
            ? Icons.dark_mode
            : Icons.light_mode,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
        provider.toggleTheme(!provider.isDarkMode);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer was perfect! Was unaware that I could just add an icon inside the widget. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As an extra question if i may ask, how can i go around styling the Icons.dark_mode and Icons.light_mode with the styles i created in the theme file? Is it worth me calling them as individual objects?

Comment: You can provide ternary expression like that or better on before icon widget while both are having different style. Like `icon: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).isDarkMode?Icon():Icon()`

Comment: I'm sorry i dont follow what you mean. `icon: IconTheme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith().iconTheme,
                      child: new Icon(Icons.dark_mode),
                    ),`
This is the code I use on other parts of my program and it works however when i try to add it here I receive alot of different errors in regards to the syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I need to have the code to test, you can also ask separate question